# Lua table contents separated at equal sign

Tags: lua

I am learning Lua, and i want to use it with Rainmeter.
In Rainmeter i use an external txt file to store skin positions with the following type of lines:

```
pza=A1
pzb=B2
pzc=D3
... (and so on...)
```

In my Lua script i made an array with reading the lines in it. So the first line is pza=A1, the second is pzb=B2, and so.
Is there any way to check only the value after the equal sign? So separating somehow the pza=A1, to get the "pza" as key, and to get "A1" as value?

Thank you very much for the help in advance!

Answer (score 4):

you can use gmatch and patterns:

```
local s=[[
    pza=A1
    pzb=B2
    pzc=D3
]]

local t= {}
for k,v in s:gmatch('(%w+)=(%w+)') do
  t[k]=v
  print(k,t[k])
end
```

result:

```
pza A1
pzb B2
pzc D3
```

Comment: Thank you your answer, and help! :)
Well the text file is modified by Rainmeter script, and i envoke the Lua script with Rainmeter, and analize the matches. So there would be around 50 keys and values. Are you saying  that the local s=[[ ]] can be replaced with the text file contents dynamically?

Comment: of course: local fname = "file.txt"    local handle = io.open(fname,"rb")   local s = handle:read('*all')

Comment: Wow, cool, it worked! :) Thank you very much! Now i just have to figure out what's what in your code in the post above :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood but try something like this where `line` would be the line you read from the file.

```
local line = "test1=100"

local delim = string.find(line, "=")
key = string.sub(line, 1, delim - 1)
val = string.sub(line, delim + 1, -1)

print("Key: "..key.." Val:"..val)
```

This will print:

> Key: test1 Val:100

Comment: Thank you for your help and answer too! :)
Well, there is a text file, which is edited by Rainmeter. The "pz" part is short for the pisition, and the after "a, b, c..." is the identifyer for the skin. So there is skin A, then the key is "pza". The value "A1" is this: i made a grid on the screen, and horizontally there are A, B, C, D, ..., and vertically are: 1, 2, 3, 4, ... .
But from Rainmeter i can use "pza" as variables, and i can use the value behind the equal sign. But i want to analize and match the values behind equal signs, and also their assigned keys. I hope i made things clearer!

Comment: I tried your method also, but it came back with the following error:
"bad argument #1 to 'find' (string expected, got nil)"

My text file's exact contents are the following:
    '
    [data]
    pza=A2
    pzb=A2
    pzc=B3
    pzd=D4
    pze=E5
    '